# Output posts relating to the tags

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, tags, woocommerce

I am using *WordPress 3.9* and *WooCommerce 2.1.8*, and wanting to know how I can show a single row of four related posts that the user is currently viewing, which is relative to the **tag** or **tags** of the post, rather than the **category** it is in.

Ideally, I'd like to display four products relating to the **tags** of the item which is currently being viewed at the bottom of my single product pages, specifically, each one of the relating post's featured images or thumbnails, and the prices.  If possible, a solution also scripted from the *functions.php* file.

The code below is what I have so far, which is displaying the related **categories** of the post, instead of the **tags** it is based on:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);

    function woocommerce_output_related_products() {
        $output = null;

        ob_start();

        woocommerce_related_products(array(
            'columns' => 4, 
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'fields' => 'ids',
            'meta_query' => $meta_query,
            'tax_query' => array(
               'relation' =>  'AND',
                 array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $cats_array
                ), 
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $tags_array
                )
            )
        )); 

        $content = ob_get_clean();
        if($content) { $output .= $content; }

        echo '<div class="clear"></div>' . $output;

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, 
Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is another filter, `woocommerce_related_products_args` in `/templates/single-product/related.php` template file, that overrides your query array.

One possible solution is to override `related.php` template, create a new template and execute custom `WP_Query` there, then include that template with `wc_get_template()` function.

The other is to take advantage of built-in filters ( quite a number of them exists ). I'll try to explain that filters here, what is their purpose, and how to use them, in the order of their execution.

---

**woocommerce_output_related_products_args**

The first filter for setting the `woocommerce_related_products()` function arguments. The function loads `related.php` template and arguments passed are the global options for the template. Arguments are `"posts_per_page"`, `"columns"` and `"orderby"`.

```
/* An example of how to set the four products per page */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_output_related_products_args', function( $args ) 
{ 
    $args = wp_parse_args( array( 'posts_per_page' => 4 ), $args );
    return $args;
});
```

At the beginning of  the template the WooCommerce `$product` object seeks the related products by category and tag. The result is an array of post ids that is later used for the `post__in` clause in main query. There are a few filters available.

**woocommerce_product_related_posts_relate_by_category**

It is used to exclude the related products by category.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_posts_relate_by_category', function() {
    return false;
});
```

**woocommerce_product_related_posts_relate_by_tag**

Exclude the related products by tag.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_posts_relate_by_tag', function() {
    return false;
});
```

**woocommerce_product_related_posts_query**

To make a final modification of the query parts.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_posts_query', function( $query ) {
    // modify $query array
    return $query;
});
```

The last filter that provides the possibility to modify the parameters for main query is `woocommerce_related_products_args`.

**woocommerce_related_products_args**

Since now the query is based on `post__in` clause, remove that part and add your custom query parts.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', function( $args ) 
{
    unset( $args['post__in'] );
    $args['tax_query'] = array( /* taxonomy parameters */ );
    return $args;
});
```

---

An example of how to display four related products relating to the tags.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_output_related_products_args', function( $args ) 
{ 
    $args = wp_parse_args( array( 'posts_per_page' => 4 ), $args );
    return $args;
});

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_posts_relate_by_category', function() {
    return false;
});
```

---

A few tips that might be helpful:

In each filter hook, if you're not sure what are the default arguments passed in, simple use `print_r` on them to see the values in browser. Also, a look at the WooCommerce source files will clarify some things. And finally, a lot of times there is no need to completely override the default WooCommerce functions, since the creators of the plugin really made the effort with all those filters to make things easier.

Comment: I rewrote the answer the best I can, so I hope that now things will be clearer.

Comment: Note that the `woocommerce_related_products_args` filter hook no longer exists.